# XMLException not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: php, android, xml, eclipse

I'm getting this error when trying to parse the XML below. I'm doing this through Android in Eclipse.

XMLException: SAXException: At line 1, column 0: not well-formed (invalid token)

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<wardrobe>
<item id="1">
    <path>images/pink.jpg</path>
    <name>pink top</name>
    <description>size 12 pink top</description>
    <category>tops</category>
</item>
<item id="2">
    <path>images/bluepants.jpg</path>
    <name>blue trousers</name>
    <description>size 10 light blue trousers</description>
    <category>bottoms</category>
</item>
<item id="3">
    <path>images/skirt.jpg</path>
    <name>grey skirt</name>
    <description>sze 10 grey skirt</description>
    <category>bottoms</category>
</item>
<item id="4">
    <path>images/runners.jpg</path>
    <name>runners</name>
    <description>exercise runners</description>
    <category>shoes</category>
</item>
<item id="5">
    <path>images/heels.jpg</path>
    <name>black heels</name>
    <description>dance shoes</description>
    <category>shoes</category>
</item>
</wardrobe>';
?>
```

I cannot find this invalid token and my XML looks the same as the w3schools example:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_server.asp

Can anybody spot this token?

Please help & thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the SAXparser is throwing because you're missing the document declaration.

The example on w3schools differs only in that regard from your own code.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>"; <-- This line.
echo "<note>";
echo "<from>Jani</from>";
echo "<to>Tove</to>";
echo "<message>Remember me this weekend</message>";
echo "</note>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks J. Steen, you're answer was very helpful. However, it turned out that the college computer I'm working from, has restricted file access so I can't parse the xml file from my phone. It worked fine in the emulator.

Comment: Oh! Wow, that's unexpected, yeah. Good luck. =)